# Simulate Tabs with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, onclick, plunker

I need to simulate a tab and I'm a noob with AngularJS, so this is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wu9b4UXb1yVgTPLFXlAG?p=info)

I don't know how I should implement a sidebar tab, here's an img, what should i do if do a onClick on my `sidebar.html` send the data of my user selected to my `profileContent.html`

[image]

Comment: Note: Angular is 2+, AngularJS is 1.x. You're currently using AngularJS, not Angular.

Comment: I think you should take a look at ui-router library https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router. Check this demo http://rp.js.org/ui-router-tabs/example/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged the code provided in the plunkr, please let me know if there are any issues.

**Plunkr:** [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/snroaNmFvRVXybgB0A4F?p=preview)

**Code:**

```
<div ng-repeat="people in peoples | filter: filtering" class="sideBarBox">
  <div class="row sideBarPosition" ng-click="selectThis(people)" ng-class="selected.name === people.name ? 'active': '' ">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="sideBarName">{{ people.name }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 sideBarArrowPosition">
      <div class="sideBarArrow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```